# Not able to iterate by selecting Partial Object in hql

Tags: hibernate, hql

how to iterate  the following code to get the output

```
String hql=" select  UserName,userId FROM org.vishwa.hibernate.UserDetails where userId>=?";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameter(0, 5);
            List users = query.list();
```

Selecting complete object i am able to iterate 
.Selecting Partial Object its not possible to iterate please provide the solution

Answer (score 1):

Please, use a named parameters (`:userId`) in place of reference parameters by a number. A such kind of query returns `List<Object[]>`

```
String hql = "select userName, userId from UserDetails where userId >= :userId";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("userId", 5);

List<Object[]> users = query.list();

for(Object[] user : users) {
  //user[0] userName
  //user[1] userId
}
```